# How to identify if a radio button is checked in selenium?

Tags: java, selenium, selenium-webdriver

I have below html code snippet for radio button .

```
 <label for="exceptionTrue">
    <span/>
    <span class="check" style="background: #F3565D;"/>
    <span class="box"/>
      Yes
    </label>
```

HTML displayed is the same if the radio button is selected or if not selected in the page.

Element is in span class='check' if the radio button is selected and is in span class='box if not selected.
Since the html code is present in page if the radio button is selected or not selected.So i cannot user verifying if class='check' .
.Any idea how i can verify this...I have tried is.Selected and it doesn't work

Comment: You mean `<span class="check" style="background: #F3565D;"/>` element is present when selected otherwise not??

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or add additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it’s hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Comment: @SaurabhGaur :The element is always present on page..When i inspect the elaement when radio button is selected it will be on <span class="check" style="background: #F3565D;"/> ..and when not selected it will be on  <span class="box"/>

Comment: I think it would help clarify the question if you posted the HTML for selected and not selected separately. `.isSelected()` only works for actual checkboxes. This is a fake checkbox so the selected state will have to be determined other ways.

Answer (score 0):

Well I don't see a problem here, you know how this radio button works and you just need to implement this verification. Find your radio button element and than:

```
if (element.getAttribute("class").equals("check")){ 
return true; }
else {
return false; }
```

This is just an example, you can adjust this to your code.

EDIT: When I read your question again it's really unclear so I'm not sure if this helps. You need to provide more details on this.

Comment: Thanks for the help.This doesn't help...<span class="check" style="background: #F3565D;"/> is always present in page irrespective of if radio button is selected or not selected,So your solution always return true in my case.